# Creating correct object structure for incoming json

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have the following script

```js
<script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        var model = [
            {
                "reservation":
                {
                    "ticketId": "782274b8-10d9-444c-8f05-3117853e3ee0",
                    "clubId": 70656,
                    "courtNumber": 1,
                    "crud_name": "add",
                    "reservationtype_name": "toernooi",
                    "players" : 
                        [
                            {
                                "player" : { "id": "18674992", "name": "Jan Jansen"}
                            },
                            {
                                "player": { "id": "19543840", "name": "Klaas Klaassen" }
                            }
                        ]
                }
            }, 
            {
                "reservation":
                {
                    "ticketId": "782274b8-10d9-444c-8f05-3117853e3ee0",
                    "clubId": 70656,
                    "courtNumber": 1,
                    "crud_name": "update",
                    "reservationtype_name": "toernooi",
                    "players":
                        [
                            {
                                "player": { "id": "18674992", "name": "Jan Jansen" }
                            },
                            {
                                "player": { "id": "19543840", "name": "Klaas Klaassen" }
                            }
                        ]
                }
            }
        ];
        alert(JSON.stringify(model));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            url: "http://localhost:59854/api/incomingapi",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) { },
            error: function (errResult) { }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have these classes

```cs
namespace MySQLTestApp.Models
{
    public class player
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReservationModelForJson
    {
        public string ticketId { get; set; }
        public int clubId { get; set; }
        public int courtNumber { get; set; }
        public string crud_name { get; set; }
        public string reservationtype_name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<player> players { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonBinder
    {
        public ReservationModelForJson reservation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my controller

```cs
public string Post(IEnumerable<JsonBinder> reservations)
{
    int clubId = reservations.First().reservation.clubId;//is 70656
    int courtNumber = reservations.First().reservation.courtNumber;//is 1
    string playerId = reservations.First().reservation.players.First().id;//is null, should be 18674992
    return "tnkx!";
}
```

The 'complex' `players` property in `reservation` don't get populated. All the simple values do! As you can see above, the `clubId` and `courtNumber` have values.

I can not change the format of the Json. I must create a correct class structure. And use this to parse the values...

Anybody knows the correct class structure to create? I cann't get it fixed...

Comment: Tip: Why not use _Json.net_ and make your life way easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate classes from JSON.

You should have:

```
public class Player2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public Player2 player { get; set; }
}

public class Reservation
{
    public string ticketId { get; set; }
    public int clubId { get; set; }
    public int courtNumber { get; set; }
    public string crud_name { get; set; }
    public string reservationtype_name { get; set; }
    public List<Player> players { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Reservation reservation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your model you should have some kind of PlayerWrapper:

```
public class playerWrapper
{
    public player player{ get; set; }
}

public class player
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class ReservationModelForJson
{
    ...
    public IEnumerable<playerWrapper> players { get; set; }
}

public class JsonBinder
{
    public ReservationModelForJson reservation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I accepted BWA's answer cause of the usefull link he provided. This answer works too!